# Delete rows based on timestamp minute

Tags: mysql, timestamp

How to delete rows based on timestamp in same minute.
ex:

```
id|temp| dt
1 | 20 | 2015-10-08 06:45:04
2 | 20 | 2015-10-08 06:40:03
3 | 21 | 2015-10-08 06:35:03
4 | 20 | 2015-10-08 06:20:04
```

I want to delete only records in the minute 5 (ids 1 and 3)
I tried `delete from table where minute(dt)=5` and works partially (?)

Comment: what works? what doesn't? please be more specific!

Comment: I guess only in timestamps = xx:x5:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
DELETE FROM mytable 
WHERE (minute(dt) - 5) % 10 = 0
```

This deletes all rows whose minute value ends at `5` (if this is what you really want).

Simpler version of the above query (thanks to @Gordon):

```
DELETE FROM mytable 
WHERE minute(dt) % 10 = 5
```